# Detect implementation of conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I want to detect if a class implements the conversion operator for a specific type, e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    operator std::map<std::string, std::string> () { ... }
}
```

I have implemented the following structure that I can used to detect this and use to select template functions to be used.

```
template<class T, class D>
struct can_convert_to
{
private:
    template<typename U> static auto check(U* t) -> decltype( static_cast<D>(*t), std::true_type());
    template<typename U> static std::false_type check(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(check<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
};
```

But, here I just check that I can convert, not that the conversion operator is defined. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: do you actually need to know whether the conversion happened with an explicitly defined conversion operator ?

Comment: `std::is_convertible` from type_traits is already implemented...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, here I just check that I can convert, not that the conversion operator is defined.

So why don't you check the existence of the operator?

```
  template <typename U>
  static auto check (U * t)
     -> decltype( t->operator D(), std::true_type{} );
```

Off topic suggestion: instead of

```
   static constexpr bool value 
      = std::is_same<decltype(check<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
```

you can simply write

```
   static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<T>(nullptr))::value;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Foo
 { operator std::map<std::string, std::string> () { return {}; } };

template <typename T, typename D>
struct can_convert_to
 {
   private:
      template <typename U>
      static auto check (U * t)
         -> decltype( t->operator D(), std::true_type{} );

      template <typename>
      static std::false_type check (...);

   public:
      static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<T>(nullptr))::value;
 };

int main ()
 {
   using mss = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

   static_assert( false == can_convert_to<Foo, int>::value, "!" );
   static_assert(  true == can_convert_to<Foo, mss>::value, "!" );
 }
```